# What's happening to my profile?

Tags: support

I keep trying to hide my e-mail address, so that it doesn't appear on my profile page. Yet like a day later, when I check, it's back on. Why does this happen?

Do I have to keep my email there? Or is it only me who can see it?

Comment: Only you can see it. Well, you and TPTB at stackexchange, in case they need to contact you (you might have more than one @addr, so the profile reminds you which one you've given them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your e-mail address in your profile page is visible only to you (and some SE employees, etc.; check the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) if that matters to you).

You can verify how your profile looks to other normal users by looking at it in a browser where you are not logged in.

Comment: Thanks! That sets my mind at rest